# Fill lookupfield in Testclass

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, relationships

I have the following code with a trigger which gives me the error:

> FLOW_ELEMENT_ERROR The flow failed to access the value for
>   myVariable_current.Product__r.ProductId__c because it hasn't been set
>   or assigned.|FlowActionCall|myRule_1_A1.

When I try to fill the `ProductId__c` field in the testclass I get:

> Field is not writeable: Product2.ProductId__c

which is a lookup. How do I solve this?

see my code:

```
trigger OrderTrigger on Order__c (after insert, after update) {

    if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isInsert){

        //Trigger Handler for creating new Opportunity 
        //or relating order to existing opportunity
        OrderTriggerHandler orderTriggerHandlerInstance = new OrderTriggerHandler();
        orderTriggerHandlerInstance.afterInsert(Trigger.New);        
    }

    if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUpdate){

        List<Order__c> newOrderListToUpdate = new List<Order__c>();
        //Filter Order__c whose End_Date__c or orderAmount
        //field is Updated
        for(Order__c order : Trigger.New){

            Order__c oldOrder = Trigger.oldMap.get(Order.Id);
            if((order.End_Date__c != oldOrder.End_Date__c ||
                order.End_Date__c != Null ||                
               order.Order_Amount__c != oldOrder.Order_Amount__c) &&
           (order.Status__c == 'A'||
            order.Status__c == 'API'||
            order.Status__c == 'AUI'||
            order.Status__c == 'AX'||
            order.Status__c == 'L'||
            order.Status__c == 'LUG1'||
            order.Status__c == 'S'||
            order.Status__c == 'SUC') && order.Journal_Code__c != 'KLP'){
                newOrderListToUpdate.add(order);
            }
        }

        //Trigger Handler for creating new Opportunity 
        //or relating order to existing opportunity        
        if(!newOrderListToUpdate.isEmpty()){
            OrderTriggerHandler orderTriggerHandlerInstance = new OrderTriggerHandler();
            orderTriggerHandlerInstance.relateOpportunity(newOrderListToUpdate);
        }        
    }
}
```

**Test class:**

```
@isTest
public class TestOderTrigger {


    static testMethod void trgOrderTest() {

        Profile profile = [Select Id From Profile where Name = 'System Administrator' limit 1];
        User usr1= new User();
        usr1.ProfileID = profile.Id;
        usr1.Username ='Test@Testemail.com'+ System.currentTimeMillis(); 
        usr1.LastName ='TestLastname';
        usr1.Email ='Test@Testemail.com';
        usr1.Alias ='TestAlia';
        usr1.TimeZoneSidKey ='TestCommunityNickname';
        usr1.CommunityNickname ='TestCommunityNickname';
        usr1.TimeZoneSidKey ='America/Los_Angeles';
        usr1.LocaleSidKey ='en_US';
        usr1.EmailEncodingKey ='UTF-8';
        usr1.LanguageLocaleKey ='en_US';
        insert usr1;
        System.runAs(usr1){




    // Create account
        Account testAccount = new Account(Name = 'Test Account');
        insert testAccount;

        system.debug(testAccount.id);


        // Create Contact
        Contact cont = new Contact();
        cont.FirstName='Test';
        cont.LastName='Test';
        cont.Accountid= testAccount.id;
        insert cont;

        system.debug(cont.id);

        // Create Opportunity
        Pricebook2 customPB = new Pricebook2(Name='Custom Pricebook', isActive=true);
        insert customPB;

        Product2 prod = new Product2(Name = 'Laptop X200', 
                                     Family = 'Hardware');
        insert prod;    

            system.debug('Product2'+prod.id);


    // Create Opportunity
        Opportunity testOpportunity = new Opportunity();
        testOpportunity.CloseDate = System.today();
        testOpportunity.AccountId = testAccount.Id;
        testOpportunity.StageName = 'Prospecting';
        testOpportunity.Name = 'Test Opportunity';
        testOpportunity.Probability = 0;
        testOpportunity.CurrencyIsoCode = 'USD';
        testOpportunity.Type = 'Upsell';
        testOpportunity.Delegate_Admin__c = cont.id;
        testOpportunity.Pricebook2Id = customPB.id;
        insert testOpportunity; 

        system.debug('testOpportunitys'+testOpportunity.id);


    // Create Order    
        Order__c testOrder = new Order__c();
        testOrder.Name = 'test';
        testOrder.CurrencyIsoCode = 'USD';
        testOrder.Account_Name__c = testAccount.id;
        testOrder.Status__c = 'A';
        testOrder.End_Date__c = System.today()+1;
        testorder.Order_Amount__c = 5555;
        testorder.Journal_Code__c = 'AZ12345';
        testorder.Product__r.ProductId__c = prod.Id;   
        insert testOrder;      
  }  
  }   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not set values using relationships. Lets take an example.

You have 3 objects i.e `A, B & C`. A is B's parent, B is C's parent. So,

```
A
|
B
|
C
```

Now, when you create a record of C, you CAN set one record of B which is going to be the parent of the new record(of type C) being created. You CAN NOT set one record of A to be the parent of B while creating a record of C. Set that while creating a record of B before jumping into C.

So you can not do this:

```
testorder.Product__r.ProductId__c = prod.Id;
```

Instead create a record of type `Product`(whichever object `testorder.Product__r` relationship is pointing to) and then use that `Product`'s Id to assign to `testorder.Product__c`(assuming its the field name of the lookup/master-detail).

**UPDATE:**

```
testorder.Product__r.ProductId__c = prod.Id;
```

- This line simply means - You have a lookup from Quote to Product
     (`testorder.Product__r` this part is telling this)
- Next, you have a field(`ProductId__c`) on Product which points to another product record.
     (`Product__r.ProductId__c = prod.Id` this part is indicating that)

So if you want to relate the quote to a product, just use `testorder.Product__c = prod.Id;` I am assuming `Product__c` is the lookup field name on Quote object.

Comment: What do you mean? I did inserted a product record in my Testclass and pointed to this product id --> prod.id.

Comment: Updated my answer with a little more explanation. Might help.